# Xdebug connection was reset in XAMPP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, magento, xampp, xdebug

I am attempting to get Xdebug to run in VSCode on Windows. I just installed Magento 2 framework in it's own directory in `xampp/htdocs/magento`.

Xdebug works fine within the `/dashboard` directory, but that's it. If I attempt to listen for Xdebug in any other directory no breakpoint will be hit and the browser will display the following error:

> 'This site can't be reached. Connection was reset.'

I've been searching for many hours for a solution but I was unable to get it to work.

This is the relevant *launch.json* configuration for VSCode:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "runtimeExecutable": "c:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
        }
```

This is the relevant *php.ini* configuration:

```ini
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.client_host=localhost
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
xdebug.log="C:\xampp\php\ext\xdebug.log"
```

The Xdebug log displays no error, here is the latest entry:

```
[14196] Log opened at 2021-10-14 12:35:22.508436
[14196] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[14196] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[14196] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/magento/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.31" protocol_version="1.0" appid="14196" idekey="VSCODE"><engine version="3.1.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2021 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[14196] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[14196] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[14196] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n notify_ok -v 1
[14196] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[14196] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n extended_properties -v 1
[14196] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[14196] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 4 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/Iksula/Appapi/Model/Home/Home.php -n 450
[14196] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="4" id="141960001" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[14196] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 5 -t line -f file:///c:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/index.php -n 3
[14196] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="5" id="141960002" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[14196] [Step Debug] <- run -i 6
```

Also in the `/apache/logs/error.log` there is nothing I could spot wrong

```
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:22.145361 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:22.147277 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 31772
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:22.501540 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 31772:tid 656] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:23.239695 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00428: Parent: child process 31772 exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:23.309464 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00455: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.3.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:23.309464 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Oct  8 2021 10:03:59
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:23.309464 2021] [core:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:23.312450 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32252:tid 600] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 29828
[Thu Oct 14 14:35:23.682622 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 29828:tid 660] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

It is unlikely that there is anything wrong with the configuration since my breakpoints DO get hit in `/dashboard/index.php` and the page loads accordingly, however if I do `/magento/index.php` the page does not even load.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: It seems that the latest Xdebug v3.1.0 TS builds are having issues on Windows (Apache from XAMPP use TS builds of PHP). Try downgrading Xdebug to the previous version: 3.0.4. Does it work now?

Comment: FWIW, Xdebug 3.1.1 has now been released, which should fix this problem too.

Comment: Updating the DLL to 3.1.1 fixed the issue, thanks!